# How do I have some authentication around "source" in Chef's data bag?

Tags: java, deployment, amazon-web-services, chef-infra

Here is the link:

https://github.com/opscode/java-quick-start/blob/master/data_bags/apps/dbapp.json#L17

In the Chef databag for Java WAR deployment we provide the source URL, which might be on S3, etc. What other sources can we have? Can we have any authentication here? Otherwise it doesn't seem to be a really awesome idea to upload my WAR to S3, publicly available (yeah, you should have direct link but still!) and use it..
If I put some bucket policy on S3, I cannot figure out the way how do I put a RULE on this S3 bucket policy to allow access to all servers from particular EC2 security group.. I don't believe there is such an option at all..

Any ideas how to solve it? Is there are any other way how we can use key, or something else, to download the "source WAR" like with SCP or something like this? If nothing else is possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas how to solve it?

The code that fetches the WAR file from wherever it is stored us at the end of the ["application::java_webapp" recipe](https://github.com/opscode/java-quick-start/blob/master/cookbooks/application/recipes/java_webapp.rb).

```
remote_file app['id'] do
  path "#{app['deploy_to']}/releases/#{app['war'][node.chef_environment]['checksum']}.war"
  source app['war'][node.chef_environment]['source']
  mode "0644"
  checksum app['war'][node.chef_environment]['checksum']
end
```

You could replace this with something that supplies credentials.

---

I couldn't find a neat solution (e.g. a "provider" for SCP), but using the "execute" resource instead of "remote_file" should do the job.  Of course, you still have the problem of arranging that the chef-client instance that runs the recipe has the right SSH key or username/password.